# ArrayList content becomes 'null' upon access?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Object `Activity` which, when initialised, looks like `Activity a = new Activity(String activityName, double calories)`. I have another Object, `ActivityPerformed` which, when initialised, looks like `ActivityPerformed ap = new ActivityPerformed(Activity a, double hours`). I also have two `ArrayLists` (an array of `Activity` and `ActivityPerformed`) and `ArrayList<ActivityPerformed>` relies on the information that is in `Activity`, that's why it has to pass through that first.

So basically the flow of information would ideally make it equivalent to this:

```
Activity a = new Activity(String activityName, double calories);
ActivityPerformed ap = new Activity(String activityName, double calories, 
                                 double hours);
```

Because adding to `ArrayList<ActivityPerformed>` requires that the `Activity` whose information its using (that's why `ActivityPerformed` uses `Activity a` instead of `String activityName, double calories`).

How do I make the information pass through properly? When I print `ArrayList<Activity>`, all the inputted activities are there, but when I print `ArrayList<ActivityPerformed>` it always prints the `double` (*both* `calories` and `hours`) as 0.0, and `activityName` as null BUT it print the correct number of items.

This is my code for adding to `ArrayList<ActivityPerformed>`

```
/**
 * Searches for the Activity record associated with the given name
 *
 * @param name the name of the Activity record to look for
 * @return     the Activity record, or null if it does not exist
 */
public Activity getActivity(String name)
{
    for(Activity a : activityBase) {
        if(a.getName().equals(name))
            return a;
    }
    return null;
}
/**
 * Track that a given kind of activity has been performed for a given number
 * of hours. If the given name does not exist in this ActivityBase, or a
 * negative number of hours is given, an error message will appear.
 *
 * @param name  the name of the activity performed
 * @param hours the number of hours that the activity has been performed
 */
public void trackActivity(String name, double hours)
{
    Activity a = getActivity(name);        
    activityPerformed.add(new ActivityPerformed(a, hours)); 
}
```

This is the code for printing ArrayList (this works on ArrayList, but maybe it's missing something that I've overlooked)

```
public String getActivityPerformed() {
    String done = "";
    for(ActivityPerformed a : activityPerformed) {
        done += a.getHours();
        done += " hours of ";
        done += a.getName();
        done += ", ";
        done += a.getTotalCalories();
        done += " calories.\n";
    }
    return done;
}
```

Under ActivityPerformed.class:

```
public ActivityPerformed(Activity a, double hours){
    a = new Activity(name, calories);
    this.hours = hours;
    this.name = name;
    this.calories = calories;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public double getTotalCalories(){
    return this.calories;
}

public double getTotalCalories(){
    return this.calories;
}
```

So how do I make `ArrayList<ActivityPerformed>` get activities from `ArrayList<Activity>` and append an extra field to it, and make it not print `null`?

Comment: Your example near the top says `ActivityPerformed = new Activity(String activityName...)`; is that a typo?

Comment: `ActivityPerformed = new Activity(String activityName, double calories, double hours);` is not valid Java.  Assuming from your description that `ActivityPerformed` is a class name, there's an identifier missing between it and the equals sign.  Then, the assignment itself is bad because you can't assign an `Activity` reference to an `ActivityPerformed` reference.

Comment: @ajb no, it's just the idea of how I want the information to pass from the Activity to the ActivityPerformed, kinda like the gist of what I sorta want to happen (not putting them apart, though). `public ActivityPerformed` shows my actual code.

Comment: @JimGarrison oops, forgot to add 'ap`. Fixed it, but that's not code i'm using, just the idea of what I want to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Culprit is this line in ActivityPerformed constructor

```
 a = new Activity(name, calories);
```

It should assign passed activity to the var a

```
this.a = a;
this.name = a.getName();  // you do not need this as Activity has this information
this.calories = a.getCalories();   // you do not need this as Activity has this information
this.hours = hours;
```

Hope this helps;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not passing name, calories, etc to ActivityPerformed constructor.
You passed the whole activity a and then ovverrode it inside the constructor.
It may be better to do:

public class ActivityPerformed {

```
Activity a;
double hours;

public ActivityPerformed (Activity a, double hours) {

    this.a = a;
    this.hours = hours;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell just what you're trying to do, but this cannot be right:

```
public ActivityPerformed(Activity a, double hours){
    a = new Activity(name, calories);
    this.hours = hours;
    this.name = name;
    this.calories = calories;
}
```

You have to pass an `Activity` to the constructor when you create a new `ActivityPerformed`; to do that, you must have created a `new Activity` already.  Instead, the above code throws that `Activity` away, creates *another* `new Activity`, and then assigns that new `Activity` into the *parameter* `a`, where it will also become useless (`a` is passed by value; therefore assigning to it will not affect anything outside the method).

If you want an `ActivityPerformed` to refer to an `Activity`, you'll need to decare a field in the `ActivityPerformed` to refer to it.  Then assign it in the constructor:

```
public class ActivityPerformed {

    Activity activity;
    double hours;

    public ActivityPerformed(Activity a, double hours) { 
        activity = a;       // sets up the reference to the Activity
        this.hours = hours;
        //this.name = name;  I don't know what this would have done, since "name"
        //     and "calories" weren't parameters to the constructor.  Most likely,
        //     this was a useless statement that assigned a field to itself.  Do you
        //     need to store these fields in the ActivityPerformed, or do you just
        //     want to use the "activity" reference to get to them?  
        //this.calories = calories;
```

Anyway, there's a lot of info missing and I can't figure out what you're trying to do.  But this should be a start.  It probably won't fix everything.

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me, I really appreciate it. Sanjeev from below showed how I can get the name and the calories from the activity (which is what I really needed), but this explanation clears everything up for me!